# If null set is an element of a set then will it belongs to set or subset?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

if $$A=\left\{\varnothing \right\}$$ we know that $A$ is a Singleton Set whose single element is a Null set. That is $A$  is a set containing another set which is Null set.

Now are these two statements True?

$1.$ $\varnothing \in A$

$2.$ $\varnothing \subset A$

Comment: With *null set* do you mean the *empty set* $\varnothing$ (`\varnothing` or `\emptyset`)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Elements**

In the notation $A=\{\varnothing\}$ everything between the curly braces (except possible commas) is considered to be an *element of the set*, and we can denote this by

$$\varnothing\in A.$$

This is nothing special about the empty set. As I said, the curly braces enclose the elements, e.g. if $B=\{\color{red}\blacklozenge,\color{blue}\bullet, 7,\times\}$ then

$$\color{red}\blacklozenge\in B,\qquad \color{blue}\bullet\in B,\qquad 7\in B\qquad \text{and}\qquad \times\in B.$$

---

**Subsets**

The statement $\varnothing\subseteq A$ is *always* true no matter how the set looks like. This is because the empty set is a subset of *all* sets without exception. Subsets model the idea of "choosing" some of the elements, not necessarily all. And you have always the option to choose none, which gives $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 6):

Both statements are true.  One can think of a set as a "bag".  Then $\emptyset$ means an empty bag.  In this case, $A=\{\emptyset\}$ means a bag containing only one element which is an empty bag.

1. $\emptyset\in A$ since $A$ contains an empty bag inside it, the empty set is an element in $A$.
2. $\emptyset\subset A$ since every element of the empty set (of which there are none) is also in $A$.

Answer (score 4):

The empty set is a subset of every set. It is also an element of your set.Thus  both statements are true.

Comment: I think this would be much clearer as three sentences:  "The empty set is a subset of every set.  It is also an element of your set.  Thus, both statements are true."  Your first sentence as written is true only in the most formal interpretation:  it is true that $\emptyset$ is an element of $\{\emptyset\}$, but knowing that "the empty set is a subset of every set" doesn't help to deduce this fact (as I would infer from the use of 'since').

Comment: thanks. I fixed it. I need a course in writing.

Comment: Writing things in public fora is a sure way to get a course in writing, whether desired or not, so a constructive attitude like yours is the best approach!  Hopefully my feedback was on the friendly side of what one gets by putting one's work in public.  :-)

Comment: I really appreciate your comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

As you say, "we know that $A$ is a Singleton Set whose single element is a Null set", so $\emptyset\in A$. Indeed, every set contains the empty set, so $\emptyset\subseteq A$ too.