# Set Theory Union of Sets Question

Tags: set-theory

I'm working on understanding a proof that trans$(x)$ if and only if 
$\cup$ S$(x)=x$, and the first part of the proof goes like this:

$\cup$S$(x)$ = $\cup$(x$\cup${x}) = $\cup$$x$$\cup$($\cup${x}) = $\cup$$x$$\cup$$x$

Essentially what is confusing me is why $\cup${x}=$x$! I understand that $\cup$$x$={$t$|$\exists$$y$$\in$$x$($t$$\in$$y$)}, so $x$$\in${x}, but I thought that $x$ is not in $x$ since $\in$ is essentially $\lt$ when talking about ordinals?

Thanks for any help understanding this!

Comment: Apparently you're confounding $x \in \{x\}$ with $x \in x$, the former being true. Thus, following your own definition, $\bigcup\{x\} = \{ t : \exists y \in \{x\} (t \in y)\}$. Since $y \in \{x\}$ yields $y = x$, it follows $\bigcup\{x\} = \{t : t \in x\} = x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2590423/415941) of mine to better understand the set notation $\{x\}$. The symbols *between* the curly braces are considerde to be the elements. Note that

$$x\not=\{x\}.$$

One is the set $x$, the other one is the set which only contains $x$ and nothing else. When you write $\bigcup \{x\}$, then you build the union of all sets *inside* of $\{x\}$, which is *only* $x$ and nothing else. And the union of a single set is the set itself, hence

$$\bigcup\{x\}=x.$$

If you want to unify all sets in $x$, then you would have to write $\bigcup x$ which is a completely other thing.