# Does null set contain one element or no elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let, A is a null set.Now which of the following is true:-

$n(A) = 1$ or,

$n(A) =0$

I knew previously that null set has 0 elements. But I saw in [quora](http://qr.ae/TUpwQC) that it contains 1 element. So now I'm confused.

If there's any problem in my question please inform me. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.com.cy/search?q=null+set+definition&oq=null+set&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j69i60j0l3.7763j1j7&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 ,greetings

Comment: You may be confusing terminology.  The empty set has no elements.  The emptyset *does* however have one *subset* (*namely itself*).  These are different phrases with different meanings.

Comment: Alternatively, the question asker and/or the answerer there on quora were confuisng it for a different question.  The question of how many elements are in $\emptyset$, (*the empty set*) the answer is zero.  The question of how many elements are in $\{\emptyset\}$ (*the set containing the emptyset*), the answer is one.  I can see how "*set of null set*" might be interpreted as $\{\emptyset\}$ instead of as $\emptyset$.  It is crucial to note here that $\emptyset\neq \{\emptyset\}$

Comment: Read the question *VERY* carefully.  The question "Does a set ***OF*** a null set contain 1 or 0 elements".  The set ***OF*** a null set is a set that has the null set as an element.  That is the $S= \{\emptyset\}$.  That is NOT the null set itself that has zero  elements.  $\emptyset$ has no elements.  But $S$ has $1$.  And $S \ne \emptyset$.  (On the other hand the answer did a lousy job actually explaining this.

Comment: [This related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2590405/if-null-set-is-an-element-of-a-set-then-will-it-belongs-to-set-or-subset?rq=1) might help provide you with more insight.

Comment: what does the terminology $n(S)$ mean?

Comment: @fleablood $n(S)$ for $S$ a finite set denotes the **n**umber of elements in $S$, i.e. it is another notation for cardinality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct the first time.

$\emptyset = \{\}$ is a set that has no elements.  So by definition the number of elements it has is .... zero.

However, sets can have sets as elements. (A set is a collection of things and there's no reason those things can't be ... other sets.)  And if you have a set that has the emptyset as an element.  That set has one element.  The empty set.

And that is what the question on Quora is *actually* asking about.  It is asking about the sets $S = \{\emptyset\}$ which has one element.  As opposed to $\emptyset = \{\}$ which doesn't have any.

......

I suppose there is a naive confusion about the difference between being a nested element within a set that is an element of a set, with being an element of a set.

If $Beatles = \{John,Paul,George,Ringo\}$ and $FictionalElephants =\{Babar, Tantor, Hathi, Pinkhonkhonk\}$ and $MyFavoriteSets = \{Beatles, FictionalElephants\}$

then how many elements does $MyFavoriteSets$ have?

- It has two: $Beatles$ and $FictionalElephants$.

Is $George$ an element of $MyFavoriteSets$.

- No.  $MyFavoriteSets$ has two elements and neither of them are
  $George$.

But $Beatles$ is an element of $MyFavoriteSets$ and $George$ is an element of $Beatles$ so isn't...?

- No!  $George$ is an *element of* $Beatles$ but $George$ *isn't*
  $Beatles$.  And it is the *sets* $Beatles$ and $FictionalElephants$
  that are the element of $MyFavoritesSets$; not the elements within
  those sets.

I suppose another abstraction barrier is that if "" is nothing and $\{\}$ has nothing in it.  Then somehow $\emptyset = \{\}$ must also be ... nothing.  So $\{\emptyset\}$ must have.... nothing in it because $\emptyset$ is nothing.

This is wrong.

Nothing is ... absence of anything.  Making a set and not putting anything in it is making the set.  The set is something.  Sets are *not* the things that are in them.  They are the sets that collect them.  So a set that collects nothing is still a set and it is something.  So "" is nothing.  $\emptyset = \{\}$ is something although it is something that has nothing inside it.  And $\{\emptyset\} = \{\{\}\}$  is something that has *something* inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The null set, or empty set,  contains no elements...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the 'null set' is, but if you mean an 'empty set', then the answer is:

the empty set $\emptyset$ contains zero elements: $$|\emptyset| = 0.$$